# How to convert a very large decimal string to hexadecimal?

Tags: rust, hex

```
let hex = "100000000000000000".as_bytes().to_hex();
// hex == "313030303030303030303030303030303030"

println!("{:x}", 100000000000000000000000u64);
// literal out of range for u64
```

How can I got that value?

In Python, I would just call `hex(100000000000000000000000)` and I get `'0x152d02c7e14af6800000'`.

`to_hex()` comes from the [hex crate](https://crates.io/crates/hex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One needs to be aware of the range of representable values for different numeric types in Rust. In this particular case, the value exceeds the limits of an `u64`, but the `u128` type accommodates the value. The following code outputs the same value as the example in Python:

```
fn main() {
    let my_string = "100000000000000000000000".to_string();  // `parse()` works with `&str` and `String`!
    let my_int = my_string.parse::<u128>().unwrap();
    let my_hex = format!("{:X}", my_int);
    println!("{}", my_hex);
}
```

Checked with the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=ca06e8507256e66841e27cef10d4e9bf):

```
152D02C7E14AF6800000
```

An explicit usage of arbitrary precision arithmetic is required in the general case. A few suggestions from [What's the best crate for arbitrary precision arithmetic in Rust?](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/77x3m8/whats_the_best_crate_for_arbitrary_precision/) on Reddit:

- `num_bigint` works on stable and does not have unsafe code.
- `ramp` uses unsafe and does not work on stable Rust, but it is faster.
- `rust-gmp` and `rug` bind to the state-of-the-art bigint implementation in C (GMP). They are the fastest and have the most features. You probably want to use one of those.

Comment: Thanks, under current circumstance `u128` is big enough for me. But, does convert it to bigint a good choice?

Comment: It depends on the semantics of the inputs and outputs. What are those strings on input and output? Where are inputs coming from? How outputs are used?

Comment: Input is always a `String`. Output for the `value` field of ethereum's transaction.

Comment: Oh, great! I missed share feature at Rust playground somehow. Link updated.

Comment: You need to consult the valid range for the `value` field of ethereum's transaction.

Common sense may provide some hints if there are no technical limits. For example, I can hardly imagine a transaction value larger than 100K EUR/USD in common-case online payment systems. Also, regulations on online money transfers apply.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I got the contracts from a App which don't cost too much. `u128` is good enough.  : )

Comment: Check out https://crates.io/crates/ibig and https://crates.io/crates/bigint-benchmark